# passing a polymorphic vectors

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an  polymorphic problem.

```
void func(std::vector< BaseClass* > A){}

std::vector< SubClass* > B;

func(B); //Compile error C2664
```

I get an error like so:

```
 error C2664 'func' : cannot convert parameter from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>' with
[
    _Ty=B *
]
and
[
    _Ty=A *
]
```

I also tried some weird stuff like have the parameter be a pointer to the vector and I pass the address of the vector like so:

```
void func(std::vector< BaseClass* > *A){}

std::vector< SubClass* > B;
func(&B); //same error
```

Comment: Would you expect to be able to pass `vector<string>` to a function that expect `vector<int>`? I bet you wouldn't. It's the same thing in your case, really - the types are unrelated.

Comment: Why would you need std::vector<SubClass *>? You could always put SubClass * in BaseClass *.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such thing as a polymorphic vector.  An
`std::vector`, and every other container type in C++, including
C style arrays always contains exactly one type.  And the fact
that two different containers have types that are related
doesn't make the types of the containers related in any way.

In your case, you'll probably have to construct a second vector:

```
func( std::vector< BaseClass* >( B.begin(), B.end() ) );
```

Note that trying to use an `std::vector<DerivedClass*>` as an
`std::vector<BaseClass*>`, say by using a `reinterpret_cast`, is
undefined behavior, and may not work.  There's no guarantee that
the actual phyical address of the `BaseClass` subobject in
a `DerivedClass` object have the same pysical address as the
complete object.

Comment: Note that OP seems to work the other way, they have a vector of `Base*` and try to get a vector of `Derived*`.

Comment: @jrok Reread his posting.  He has a vector `B` of type `DerivedClass*`, and he wants to call a function `func` which takes a vector of `BaseClass*`.

Answer (score 6):

Templates to the rescue:

```
template<typename T>
void func(std::vector<T> A)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This looses type safety (replacing static type checking with duck typing, and resulting is very strange error messages if you do pass an invalid type), and requires putting the implementation of `func` in a header file, increasing coupling.  It's fine if `func` is very simple, and very stable, but should be avoided otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that `this` *is-a* `that` doesn't mean that a *collection* of `this` is a *collection* of `that`.

Consider what could happen if what you wanted were allowed:

```
void func(std::vector<BaseClass*>& A)
{
    A.push_back(new BaseClass);
}

std::vector<SubClass*> B;

func(B);
```

Oops! `B` now contains something which *isn't* a pointer to `SubClass`, and a program that dereferences it is undefined.

You need to make a copy with the correct type, use templates, or refactor so you don't need to pass the collection around.

Comment: Very good point concerning the type safety.  (There are technical reasons why it isn't implementable, regardless of the type safety issue, but the type safety issue means that it _shouldn't_ be implemented, even if it were possible.)